# Just finished Spivak. How does real analysis differ?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I just finished working through and understanding everything in Calculus by Michael Spivak. Now I'm contemplating reading Rudin, since it's said commonly that real analysis is the next step. I just realized though, I don't really understand what Rudin has that Spivak doesn't. *Calculus* formally defines limits, convergence, derivatives, integrals and everything. How exactly does Rudin (and real analysis in general) differ? I previously thought they differed roughly by rigor, but Spivak has covered what I previously thought was real analysis.

Comment: The level of rigor between calculus and real analysis is huge. It teaches you more than just the formula manipulation you learn in calculus.

Comment: Sure, that holds for the Calculus I learnt before reading Spivak (I took Calculus I, II and III, and they were very non-rigorous). Spivak's book covered the concepts of calculus rigorously (most exercises were proof exercises), but it still didn't call itself real analysis. What am I missing? Besides the rigor, are there concepts in real analysis that aren't in calculus?

Comment: @Silynn: Spivak's book can hardly be said to deal only with "formula manipulation"...

Comment: If you are interested in real analysis and measure theory, try "Real Analysis: Measure Theory, Integration, and Hilbert Spaces" by Elias M. Stein & Rami Shakarchi. That is awesome.

Comment: @user162357: I think the missing part is measure theory and function spaces!

Comment: @symplectomorphic Sorry, don't have access to any of the newer versions of Spivak's regular Calculus, only Calculus On Manifolds (which was rigorous). But as for missing topics, looks like: Metric spaces, Basic Topology (compactness and connectedness and such), Constant Rank theorem, and generalizations of the Riemann integral (including measure theory)

Comment: There is a lot more to mathematics than the Euclidean metric and the real line.

Comment: I would describe baby Spivak as an ideal transition from high school to university mathematics; it is still introductory real analysis. The underlying difference in Royden, Rudin and Pugh is generalisation to metric spaces, Weierstrass, Lebesgue integration, ... They cover more advanced topics.

Comment: You should plan carefully how to invest your time before choosing the next book, which means looking at many books (in a library -- use interlibrary loan if necessary) yourself and not just relying on what others say. That said, I think a natural "next book" would be Fleming's [**Functions of Several Variables**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0387902066). When I was an undergraduate (late 1970s) this book was somewhat like a Spivak-level undergraduate advanced calculus text (used for honors sections, being too hard for the regular sections).

Comment: Just want to be clear that even Spivak himself says (in the preface to the more recent editions, if I recall correctly) that his *Calculus* is really an introduction to real analysis and probably would be named accordingly if written today.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are plenty of concepts from real analysis that aren't in Spivak's text. There are two main *concrete* directions to go, and a variety of abstract directions to go.

First there are function spaces. The main important concept that function spaces introduce is that there are different kinds of convergence which have different properties.

One of the most important examples is as follows. Suppose $f_n$ is a sequence of continuous functions on $[a,b]$. If they converge uniformly to $f$, i.e. $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in [a,b]} |f_n(x)-f(x)| = 0$, then $f$ is continuous. But if they converge pointwise, i.e. for every $x$ we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = f(x)$, then $f$ may not be continuous. The classic counterexample is $f_n(x) = x^n$ on $[0,1]$.

Second there is Lebesgue integration. It turns out that the Riemann integration studied in calculus has bad analytic properties. A nice property that we very often want is that if $f_n \to f$ pointwise, then $\int f_n dx \to \int f dx$. Riemann integration makes it very difficult to guarantee this property. In particular it is very difficult to guarantee that the right hand side even makes sense. Lebesgue integration defines integration in such a way that the right hand side will *always* make sense, and gives a number of convenient criteria to guarantee that the convergence I described above will occur. As a bonus, a huge wealth of new functions become integrable, and a framework for integration over spaces other than $\mathbb{R}^n$ appears.

The abstract directions are numerous. However, they usually begin with metric spaces. I will let someone else discuss the relevance of this topic.

Comment: Hi! Could you please give a little indication of the abstract areas one could go into? I’m just looking for a very brief overview, or even just a few names

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're doing this for self-study. Personally, I would recommend against baby Rudin (Principles of Mathematical Analysis) and even moreso green Rudin (Real & Complex analysis). It's not that Rudin isn't good -- he's great -- but I don't think it's a good progression. I'll suggest a few directions for you to go in.

- Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds*. This will require you know some basic linear algebra, and you might have to check a few definitions, but this might be an exciting continuation of your course on calculus. You would be familiar with the style of writing, and more importantly, the book is absolutely fantastic. Multivariable calculus really takes on a life of its own, and you can really feel the full force of everything you've just learned with immense applications to real-life phenomena, especially electromagnetism. To this end, *Div, grad, curl and all that* is an equally charming book that could whet your appetite.
- Stein and Shakarchi's *Princeton lectures in analysis, Vol. 1 : Fourier Analysis*. The text is very readable, and most importantly, doesn't require you to know about Lebesgue integration. Moreover, Fourier analysis motivates a *lot* of analysis. You might get lost pretty quickly, but then you get start going through an introductory analysis textbook (like Bartle and Sherbert).
- Something completely different! Analysis is just one part of mathematics. I think it's a great idea to get an early exposure to group theory. I learned from John & Margaret Maxfield's *Abstract algebra and solutions by radicals*. It introduces you to groups, permutations, Cayley's theorem, the basics of rings and fields and even field extensions, all in a pretty accessible short book.

Comment: I already know multivariate calculus in a kind of mechanical way, just like "knew" calculus in a mechanical way before reading Spivak. Is Calculus on Manifolds similar in that way? I already know the vector calculus concepts like div, grad and curl and how to "apply" them to various situations.

Also, I have been recommended by a friend to read Analysis on Manifolds by Munkres. Thoughts? Or should I maybe read spivak